# Visual Studio 2010 or 2008 after Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Professional for web applications development mainly on my workstation. Now Development team is looking to upgrade it to upper versions. I am confused whether I should upgrade first to 2008 or I should switch on 2010. Please specify which will be better choice and why?
Do All applications of 2005 will work fine after upgrading them to 2010? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be already on Visual Studio 2010, the Extension feature is excellent!

There is no reason to stick with 2005 or 2008

Answer (score 0):

The last stable version is 2010, and there are currently Visual Studio 11 but still Beta version.

I advise you to wait until a Visual Studio 11 it is released, and then upgrade to it.

As you know, because every version contains new developments and Ease more.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 works fine with 2005 applications. I dont see a point in upgrading to 2008 and then upgrading to 2010 and do twice the work.